# SVN CodeBrag Integration for window application code review

Tags: git, svn, tortoisesvn, git-svn

We are planning to use [codebrag tool](http://codebrag.com/) for code review purpose,here we found that codebrag work with SVN so we use tortoise SVN here.

I found Codebrag only understand git format so we used,

```
git svn clone file:///C/SVNPREPO
```

`SVNREPO` is SVN repository for my case.

My codebrag.conf is like:

```
codebrag {  
    data-dir = "./data"  
    repos-root = "./repos"  
    send-anon-usage-data = false  
    web-server-port = 8080  
    application-url = "http://localhost:8080"

    
    required-reviewers-count = 1

    
    pull-sleep-period {
        enabled = false
        from = 22
        to = 5
} }
```

I think, `web-server-port = 8080` and URL is not for my case at my SVN Repo is in same PC, and this is for Window C# Application so no url and port is require.

Removing this setting give me error.

Could anybody advise here.

Answer (score 1):

`web-server-port` and `application-url` are for `Codebrag` web interface. You can change the port but cannot remove it.

Comment: we are working on window software ( C#, Visual Studio, VISIOSVN), here no web interface. how can I setting as per my requirement. Is codebrag handle only web application code review?

Comment: This is web interface of `Codebrag` itself. How are you going to review code without an interface? Well, `Codebrag` has web interface to perform review.

Comment: No, it means it's an application with web interface.Written in Java, it can be run on any platform.

Comment: how web interface is possible for window application? we have a .exe file to run the program and C# files where code review is require.

Comment: The interface is for the the review. It has nothing to do with the rest of the application.

Comment: Web interface is possible at Windows because any program can be a web server. Codebrag is such a program.